# SQLite - Using a hyphen in a column alias

Tags: sqlite

**EDIT**: Have been using SQLiteBrowser as an IDE\Tool

Not a frequent user of SQLite - please forgive my ignorance.
The query below is part of a bigger query;

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.Material AS "Diameter", 
                T2.sLength  AS "0-110mm", 
                T3.sLength  AS "110-160mm", 
                T4.sLength  AS "225-300mm", 
                T5.sLength  AS "300-450mm", 
                T6.sLength  AS "450-600mm", 
                T7.sLength  AS "600mm-" 
FROM   "mycte" T1 
       LEFT JOIN "mycte" T2 
              ON T1.Material = T2.Material 
                 AND T2.Diameter = "0-110mm" 
       LEFT JOIN "mycte" T3 
              ON T1.Material = T3.Material 
                 AND T3.Diameter = "110-160mm" 
       LEFT JOIN "mycte" T4 
              ON T1.Material = T4.Material 
                 AND T4.Diameter = "225-300mm" 
       LEFT JOIN "mycte" T5 
              ON T1.Material = T5.Material 
                 AND T5.Diameter = "300-450mm" 
       LEFT JOIN "mycte" T6 
              ON T1.Material = T6.Material 
                 AND T6.Diameter = "450-600mm" 
       LEFT JOIN "mycte" T7 
              ON T1.Material = T7.Material 
                 AND T7.Diameter = "600mm-" 
WHERE  T1.Material <> ''
```

And while I use an alias with a single hyphen\minus in the alias, the fields return empty.
If I rename the alias "0-110mm" to "0--110mm", the column's fields return data.
It would seem as if a single hyphen\minus is messing things up.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which programming language are you using to access SQLite?

Comment: SQL - using SQLiteBrowser (which allows CTEs) but the client is on SQLiteStudio (which does not allow CTEs!). To answer your question, I am not calling from application code.

Answer (score 0):

Best I've managed to come up with it this. Just have to deal with the trailing space in the name.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     T1.Material AS "Diameter"
    ,T2.sLength  AS [0-110mm ]
    ,T3.sLength  AS [110-160mm ]        
    ,T4.sLength  AS [160-225mm ]
    ,T5.sLength  AS [225-300mm ]    
    ,T6.sLength  AS [300-450mm ]    
    ,T7.sLength  AS [450-600mm ]
    ,T8.sLength  AS [600mm- ]   
FROM "MyCTE" T1
LEFT
JOIN "MyCTE" T2 ON T1.Material = T2.Material AND T2.Diameter = "0-110mm"
LEFT
JOIN "MyCTE" T3 ON T1.Material = T3.Material AND T3.Diameter = "110-160mm"
LEFT
JOIN "MyCTE" T4 ON T1.Material = T4.Material AND T4.Diameter = "160-225mm"
LEFT
JOIN "MyCTE" T5 ON T1.Material = T5.Material AND T5.Diameter = "225-300mm"       
LEFT
JOIN "MyCTE" T6 ON T1.Material = T6.Material AND T6.Diameter = "300-450mm"
LEFT
JOIN "MyCTE" T7 ON T1.Material = T7.Material AND T7.Diameter = "450-600mm"
LEFT
JOIN "MyCTE" T8 ON T1.Material = T8.Material AND T8.Diameter = "600mm-"
```

Comment: Mark, which version of SQLite are you using? Also, I retract my answer from earlier!

Comment: I'm unsure of how to determine the version of SQLite but when opening the db file in notepad, i see "SQLite format 3" as the first part of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which version of SQLite you are using but the following fiddle demonstrates your initial approach working correctly:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/20222/1

```
CREATE TABLE test 
  ( 
     col1 VARCHAR(100) 
  ); 

INSERT INTO test 
            (col1) 
SELECT 'foo' 

SELECT col1 AS "col-1" 
FROM   test
```

Comment: Thanks Drew - I'm starting to wonder if the problem is not because of the tool\ide\browser I am using. I was using SQLIteBrowser (which allows CTEs) but the client is on SQLiteStudio (which does not allow CTEs!). Will see if the aliasing problem persists...

Comment: @MarkD welcome. And gotcha. Also, it looks as though SQLite supports CTEs in general? Also, have you tried to maybe execute the statement via the command line interface to sqlite?

Comment: Yes, SQLite does support CTEs - but the client will not accept the code because it does not run in SQLiteStudio - the fun! Have not tried the cmd line interface; just going to stick to their toolset and try to satisfy. BTW - the alias "problem" persisted in SQLiteStudio.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use double quotes or square brackets for your aliases. Use single quotes instead. That may fix the problem. I had a similar problem the other day, not the same but similar.

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

'keyword'       A keyword in single quotes is a string literal.
"keyword"       A keyword in double-quotes is an identifier.
[keyword]       A keyword enclosed in square brackets is an identifier. This is not standard SQL. This quoting mechanism is used by MS Access and SQL Server and is included in SQLite for compatibility.